# How to search a DataFrame for a specific string using a wildcard

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wildcard, na

I have a DataFrame that has a column that I need to search using a wildcard. I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('CHQ REG.xlsx',index=False)
df.sort_values(['CheckNumber'], inplace=True)
df[df.CheckNumber.str.match('888')]
df
```

This returns everything in by df

Here is my goal:

```
CheckBranch  CheckNumber
  Lebanon      8880121
```

Sample:

```
CheckBranch     CheckNumber
  Texas            4782436
  Georgia          8967462
  Lebanon          8880121
  China            8947512
```

Comment: What would be the meaning of the wildcard, match will already work for any string starting with 888 if you remove the `*`

Comment: So I remove the error I was getting with calling dropna correctly, but when I run match('888') it brings up all the rows in the df.

Comment: Add a sample of your df, with also the expected output and the current output

Comment: I posted some samples and expected above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
res = df[df['CheckNumber'].astype('string').str.match('888')]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  CheckBranch  CheckNumber
2     Lebanon      8880121
```

As an alternative:

```
res = df[df['CheckNumber'].astype('string').str.startswith('888')]
```

Comment: Yes it worked but what does the astype do? I assumed that the .str.match told python to look for a string?

Comment: astype converts the series to string type